# How to configure using specific directories for TeamCity VCS

Tags: version-control, ant, teamcity

In TeamCity I have Version Control settings connected to a git repo, however that repo contains two directories that each have build.xml files (for ant) I wish to only execute tests in one folder. Unsure how to specify a specific directory in my TeamCity project, as it's not finding build.xml in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Edit Configuration Settings
2. Then Build Steps -> Create if needed
3. Edit Build Step -> Set **Working Directory** as directory in repo
4. Run the project build and it should point to specific directory